# objective c synchronousrequest query

Tags: objective-c, sendasynchronousrequest

I am trying to use some objective c code to upload an image and some text data to my webserver which all works fine.  I was just trying to add a basic progress indication "text box" to my display to show the progress i.e say "uploading"

I am using the following code in a buttons IBAction to kick off the upload

```
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

This effectively stops me from being able to update a text description box (or any screen parameter) until the upload has finished (by the nature of a synchronous action i suppose) How can I update some screen parameters prior to the upload starting (but still within the buttons IBAction)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendSynchronousRequest` is, as the name indicates, *synchronous* and therefore blocks
the current thread. Since all UI updates are only done when program control returns
to the main event loop, you have to move the upload to a separate thread,
for example like this:

```
self.progressLabel.text = @"Uploading...";
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:...];

        // UI activity must be done on the main thread again:
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            self.progressLabel.text = @"Done.";
        });
    });
```

Alternatively, you can use `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:...]`.